# prove that if gcd(a,b) = 1, then gcd(a,a+b) = 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So I need to prove that if gcd(a,b) = 1, then gcd(a,a+b) = 1. How do I go about it? I tried going with the ax + by = 1 method but it didn't work out so well.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should have worked out well, as
$$ax+by = 1$$
can be rewritten as
$$a(x-y) + (a+b)y = 1$$
And since $x-y$ is an integer, we can just call it $x'$, and then we have
$$ax'+(a+b)y = 1$$